# magnifying moving images

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

im developing a 2d game on iphone in which i want to maginify the views on the screen to give the effect that the user is looking through the sniper whenever the user taps the screen..
i am required to show that the objects which the player wants to shoot should be moving...so im incremeting their position as well as increasing their size...
so i want this magnified image to show the updated positions of the moved objects at runtime to give the effect that the user is looking through the snpier...
scaling the images didnt help me cause it slowed my application a llot as the objects position is updated every 0.01 sec...
please help

Answer (score 0):

Is it a 2d game, or are you using OpenGL ES? If the latter, you can always render your scene to a texture and use the hardware to scale that for you. That shouldn't slow down the game too much...
If 2d, it's always faster to scale one single image than a lot of individual objects, so here it also may be beneficial to render to an image first, and later scale and draw it on the screen.

Comment: can you please tell me how would i render the area containing more than one imageviews and scale as im very new to iphone development and have neverrendered a image before...